# git clone fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/snsnsjsn/allen.github.io/': OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054

Tags: git, github

i first time to create github.io page follow https://pages.github.com/

i have create repository , and install git.exe local win10, them
`git clone https://github.com/username/username.github.io`

but get the wrong info.

````
Cloning into 'username.github.io'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/username.github.io/': OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054```
````

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the default, a proxy, or any sort of TLS MITM device?

Answer (score -1):

you can use by

```
 git config --global http.sslVerify "false" 
 git config --global https.sslVerify "false"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.